# How to return all descendants (both relationships and nodes) till the leaf of a node (identified by label and id) including node itself using cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am new to neo4j and cypher. I wanted to get all descendants till the leaves of a node, including the node itself. The graph looks like below:

[image]

I want a specific "W" with all its descendants till the leaf as the following JSON format:

```
[
  { source: {label: "node_label", type="node_type"}, type:"rel_type", target: {label: "node_label", type="node_type"} }
]
```

I tried the following queries:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) WITH collect({ source: id(a), target: id(b), type: type(r) }) AS links RETURN links
```

But it returns all the "W"s. If I try the following:

```
MATCH (a:W {wid: $wid})-[r]->(b) WITH collect({ source: id(a), target: id(b), type: type(r) }) AS links RETURN links
```

I get only the first relationship of "W" having wid as property.

Can anyone please help me with the right Cypher syntax for my task?

Regards,

Comment: Do you find this [Neo4j developer doc for find longest paths](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/achieving-longestpath-using-cypher/) useful?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I don't need the path between two nodes. Instead, I need the complete downward tree starting from a specific "W" node.

Comment: The tech article has a [link to the APOC documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) where you may find what you want.